# Do Adjacency Lists from Binary Trees go both ways?

Tags: graphs, binary-trees, adjacency-matrix

From my reading and research it appears it's one way, however my lecturer states that it goes both ways in his examples.

Let me show you what i mean by this.

He claims that a binary tree built from a heap with numbers 1 - 7 appears as:

1->2->3

2->1->4->5

3->1->6->7

4->2

5->2

6->3

7->3

Whereas i would say it appears as:

1->2->3

2->4->5

3->6->7

4

5

6

7

Because the tree is moving in one direction, down from the root.

Are both ways valid? Is this the difference between a directed and undirected rendition maybe? Or is there one set way?

Answer (score 0):

There are different 'families' of trees, and sometimes the borderline is slightly unclear.

In graph theory a tree usually is an undirected (simple) graph that is connected and has no cycles. There is no natural direction in the graph.

Additionally one might declare one of the nodes to be the root. Then, like you observe, this automatically induces a direction of the edges away from the root. Now it is a matter of taste. Is it still an undirected graph (a 'rooted tree') or is the structure directed (a 'directed tree').

Even in diagrams of trees this might be unclear. Usually one draws the root at the top and the leaves near the bottom. But even when the edges are undirected lines, the tree might be considered top-to-bottom directed.

I sympathise with your view, but of course I am not your lecturer.